# Deleting RecyclerView Row with visible button not working as expected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So I have a weird bug which I think I've introduced into my code. It involves a RecyclerView.

So when a user wants to delete a row in my app, the following should occur:

1. User long presses row
2. Delete row button becomes visible.
3. User clicks button to delete the row.
4. Confirmation dialog shows (this is yet to be implemented but *should* be easy).
5. If user confirms, remove row from RecyclerView and update.

Now, I can get steps 1 through 5 working for each row... However, if I delete more than one (usually two) rows, something strange happens, a few rows down, the Delete Project button appears and if I long press any other row (and the one in question) the visible buttons reverse. (If that makes sense?)

How do I prevent this from happening? Here's my code so far:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ProjectListAdapter.ItemClickListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
        mPLA.onRowLongClick(position, mRV_ProjectList);
    }
    ...
}
```

ProjectListAdapter.java:

```
public class ProjectListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProjectListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final in position) {
        ...
        holder.b_deleteProject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onButtonDeletePress(position);
            }
        });
    }
    ...
    public void onDeleteButtonPress(int position) {
        if(getItem(position) != null) {
            ProjectManager.getInstance().removeProject(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, ProjectManager.getInstance().getProjectListSize());
        }
    }
    ...
    public void onRowLongClick(int position, RecyclerView rv) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rv.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
        holder.setDeleteProjectButtonVisibility();
    }
    ...
}
```

In the ViewHolder class within ProjectListAdapter.java has:

```
public void setDeleteProjectButtonVisibility() {
    if(b_deleteProject.getVisibility() == Button.VISIBLE) { b_deleteProject.setVisibility(Button.GONE); }
    else if (b_deleteProject.getVisibility() == Button.GONE) { b_deleteProject.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE); }
    else { b_deleteProject.setVisibility(Button.GONE); }
}
```

That is all I think is related to the issue, if it's not then I can proved further code.

I'm scratching my head at the moment as to what is causing it (highly likely something I'm not doing right).

Thanks!

Comment: issue is like when you click on second row and scroll the recyclerview then that delete button is also getting visible there?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you can do this with taking one boolean in you model and handle visibility for only that particular position.

Example take one boolean like isDeleteProject in your model. Then use getter setter to change the value according to your requirement like below.

```
  public void onRowLongClick(int position, RecyclerView rv) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rv.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
    mRV_ProjectList.get(position).setIsDeleteProject(true);
    holder.setDeleteProjectButtonVisibility(position);
}


public void setDeleteProjectButtonVisibility(int Position) {
if(mRV_ProjectList.get(position).isDeleteProject())
 {
     b_deleteProject.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE)
     mRV_ProjectList.get(position).setIsDeleteProject(false);
 }
```

Also by default in xml make is visiblity gone.